# how to add login with phone number wihile using django allauth package

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-allauth

I am using Django all auth package (google) how can I set up login with phone number feature to it?

can someone please guide me

Comment: did you find a way?

Comment: nope i try twillo but didn't work out